# How to get all property values?

Tags: neo4j

How to iterate over all property values for a node in Cypher? I can iterate over keys by doing:

```
"WHERE any (key in keys(n) where key ='xxx')"
```

Is there a similar way to do this for property value?

I need to test each key value to see whether the key value equals a variable. If matching, I issue a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this syntax for accessing the value for a node property key:

```
WHERE any (key in keys(n) where n[key] ='xxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or where exists n.key
AND n.key = 'toto'

Comment: I will test it. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with that one is it is literally comparing the value of the property named "key", it's not using the key String variable.